# Terminal does not appear in launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

Whenever I open a terminal in Ubuntu, it does not appear in the launcher, as depicted in the following screenshot.

It doesn't even show up when I press Alt+Tab! Is this a bug? Is there a known solution?

[image: screenshot where the unity dock does not show the open terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is a bug of some systems. Read it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/960282). Maybe there can be other work around to it. I will post it tomorrow, if that is so.
Maybe the weather applet is causing the problem. If then, just give a try to cut the weather applet from the conf file under `.config/cairo-dock/current_theme` everything may work fine.

Comment: Thank you. But the bug link does not explain why it does not appear in the Alt+Tab windows. Are they related?

Comment: Just try to look [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calibre/+bug/988581), maybe this could explain or take you somewhere. I got interested for what they quoted:<br> `Hit Super+W, This works and is currently the only way to switch to calibre, for me. `

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. The terminal did not show up in the Laucher or when using Alt+Tab. This was after migrating my Ubuntu 12.04 installation to a new laptop.

Solution: Uninstall gnome-terminal using Ubuntu software center and re-install it right afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problems. I couldn't consistently get the terminal to show up in the dock, and even if it did, it might not show up via Alt+Tab, or clicking the icon might not do anything or might create a new terminal window rather than switching to an existing one. Here's how I finally managed to "fix" it:

1. Create an executable shell script file containing just the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gnome-terminal
   ```
2. Create a .desktop file linked to that shell script; I did this by running `gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/gterm.desktop` from inside a terminal window (you need the `gnome-panel` package; if you need further instructions, you should be able to find them by Googling "gnome-desktop-item-edit").
3. Open the directory containing the .desktop file, and run it by double-clicking. (You *might* need to first make sure you don't have any terminal windows open.) You should see an icon for it appear in the dock. Right-click on that icon and select "Lock to Launcher".

You should now have a properly working dock icon for your terminal. Apparently the fact that it's running a shell script, rather than running the terminal command directly, gets around whatever was causing the problems.

If anyone has a cleaner solution, I would love to see it. But unless and until that happens, I hope this method can at least help people get things working properly on the surface.

EDIT: After going through all this, I did something that required a reboot. After the reboot, there was an icon for the actual Terminal in the dock, in addition to the one for the shell script I had created. Both icons seem to work how I would want them to, so I've deleted the shell script one. So a reboot might be all that's needed. I'll leave the shell script method here in case anyone can't get this working just by rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I uncommented the three blocks under the `/* notebook */`
tag in

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css
```

to fix another [bug](http://markmail.org/message/v5nbhfnqp5ypovpo#query:+page:1+mid:v5nbhfnqp5ypovpo+state:results).

I've fixed this problem restoring such file, clicked over terminal icon (on the dock) when it restarted and clicked on "Keep on the launcher".

I uncommented again the same blocks and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems with icons, the launcher and <kbd>ALT-TAB</kbd>bing.

The fix, for me, was to disable the call to `conky` in my machine startup script.

NOTE: I just transitioned from v1.9 of `conky` to v1.10. Before disabling it, `conky` v1.10 was erroring out (`conkyrc` translation issue).

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me in `gnome-shell` after I've upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04.

I say "similar thing", because the Terminal window did show up for me when I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, but it did not show up in launcher.

The way I fixed it was to go into Activities Overview (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd>), search for the Terminal app, right click it, and choose `Remove from favourites`.

After that it started showing up correctly, even after I added it back to favourites.