# Terminal doesn't show up in the launcher

Tags: command-line, launcher

Note: This question: [Terminal does not appear in launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130746/terminal-does-not-appear-in-launcher) is very similar, but it was for 12.04. Will those answers still work in 13.04?

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu and I was updating/installing my programs and I noticed that terminal didn't show up on the launcher bar or in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> window-thingy.

This is somewhat annoying, as if I minimize the windows they are lost as far I can tell.

Comment: Ok, did you tried any of these answers? Those doesn't seem version specific solutions.

Comment: Never mind. I rebooted and it works fine now. Oh well.

Comment: I think you are old enough to know that you can answer your own questions.

Comment: Yes, I know I can. And I did now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminal does not appear in launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130746/terminal-does-not-appear-in-launcher) (since it appears that turned out to work after all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I restarted and it works fine.